# Is "Fight or Flight" distance genetic

Tags: genetics

If you took a newborn animal and completely isolated it from its species, would it be capable of assuming a fight or flight distance preset by its species, due to their being no basis for what could harm the animal?

Comment: What do you mean by "distance"? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

It probably is somewhat genetic.  A good example is pigeons.  When you approach them, they turn their back to you so that if you get close enough they can escape / fly away.  I'd be surprised if this is only a learned behavior, but I also note that pigeons who have been fed let you approach to a closer distance than other birds, so in this example a distance is not completely hard wired.

Such behaviors are more likely a combination of learned and genetic, especially as the animal becomes more complex (has a larger brain).  This is a major concern of '[ethology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethology)'.

I think few inherited behaviors are [completely inflexible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethology#Fixed_action_patterns_and_animal_communication).